# SQL Server is trying to use two paths for backup location

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, backup

I am struggling with a backup job created under Maintenance Plans for one installation.

A "Back Up Database Task" is set for specific databases, option "Disk" is selected, as well as "Create a backup file for every database", and "Create a sub-directory for each database". Folder is set as a browseable UNC path:

```
\\\backupserver\SQLBack\servername
```

View T-SQL shows the same correct backup location:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [DBName] 
TO DISK = N' \\\backupserver\SQLBack\servername\DBName\DBName_backup_2018_04_27_141724_2876433.bak' 
WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, 
     NAME = N'DBName_backup_2018_04_26_141724_2856433', 
     SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD, NO_COMPRESSION,  STATS = 10
```

Everything looks great, but the actual path is failing with the actual path being different from what it should be:

> Executing the query "BACKUP DATABASE [DBName] TO  DISK = N' \\..."
>   failed with the following error: "Cannot open backup device
>   'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Backup\
>   \\backupserver\SQLBack\servername\\DBName\DBName_backup_2018_04_26_124542_5356659.bak'.

I can't figure out why is it appending `C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL.1\\MSSQL\\Backup\\` to the entered backup location, any help is appreciated.

Both locations are available to the SQL Server.

Comment: Check the extra space in `TO DISK = N' \\backupserver\`. Right after the `N' `. My guess is that the backup task is seeing that extra space and switching it to your default SQL install location.

Comment: I'll be damned. Thank you, with that space removed it is backing up successfully!

Comment: OK, just confirmed. The extra space will cause the backup process to prepend your default SQL backup location.

Comment: I never knew it would do that either. Learned something new today. :-)

Comment: Take a look at this. This might also help:  https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/107157-problem-with-sql-backups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra space in `TO DISK = N' \\..."`, after the `N'`. This will cause the default SQL backup location to be prepended to the `TO DISK` setting. Removing that extra space will allow it to backup normally.

Comment: Thank you again! I was fooled by View T-SQL script.

Comment: @user2101153 Can you accept the response as the answer please?